# Can I manage dynamic controllers based on $stateParams?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm working with ui-router. I know of to set a dynamic templateUrl but I'd like to manage a dynamic controller.

Here is what I'm looking for:

```
$stateProvider.state('town.building', {
    url: "/building?id",
    templateUrl: function ($stateParams) { // Working dynamic templateUrl
        if ($stateParams.hasOwnProperty('id')) {
            switch (Number($stateParams.id)) {
            case 1:
                return "views/factory.html";
            /* case 2, case 3, etc. */
            default:
                return null;
            }
        }
        return null;
    },
    controller: function ($stateParams) { // Dynamic controller ?
        if ($stateParams.hasOwnProperty('id')) {
            switch (Number($stateParams.id)) {
            case 1:
                return "myFirstController";
            /* case 2, case 3, etc. */
            default:
                return "defaultController";
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
});
```

Is it possible to do something like that ? Am I going the wrong way ?

Comment: returning a string from controller won't do anything...the reference angular uses is the function itself, not what it returns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would do:

```
$stateProvider
     .state('intermediary-state', {
              url:     '/',
              onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state',
                function ($stateParams, $state) {
                  if ($stateParams.id === '1') {
                    $state.go('somewhere');
                  } else {
                    $state.go('somewhere-else');
                  }
                }]
            })
     .state('somewhere', {
              url:     '/somewhere',
              controller: 'SomewhereCtrl'
            })
     .state('somewhere-else', {
              url:     '/somewhere-else',
              controller: 'SomewhereElseCtrl'
            });
```

The logic behind this is that I'm using an intermediary state which only grabs the stateParams, evaluates and redirects accordingly.

---

This being said, I'm not sure why would you need your controllers to be dynamic based on the stateParams. It seems like a code smell to me as well, and a better option is to depend on an underlying service.

For example your might have a different "home" state/controller for the logged in user versus the guest user, and the AuthenticationService is responsible of that logic.

```
$stateProvider
     .state('intermediary-state', {
              url:     '/',
              onEnter: ['authenticationService', '$state',
                function (authenticationService, $state) {
                  if (authenticationService.isLoggedIn()) {
                    $state.go('home-user');
                  } else {
                    $state.go('home-guest');
                  }
                }]
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that doing that for controllers is a good idea. First of all,

```
return "myFirstController";
```

won't work, as it was already noticed in comments. You will need

```
$controller("myFirstController");
```

instead, which is intended for testing and hacking, not for trivial usage. Consider its appearance a warning of code smell.

And the good thing is that you don't need to define controllers in router at all, you can choose the proper controller for the view right within template files with `ng-controller`.